# The checkboxed records must be deleted from the database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a website actually, and i'm stuck. My website display data from my database in a table. Every last column in the table is a checkbox. If i "check" the checkbox, i want to delete the checkboxed record from the database. Any helping hand would be helpful.

If i press the Delete button i want to delete the topic which line is checkboxed.

Here's the source code:

```
echo '<table align="center" border="1" style="width:50% "><tr><th>Fórum neve</th><th>Tulajdonos</th><th>Létrehozás ideje</th><th>Hozzászólások száma</th><th>Törlés</th></tr>';

$sql = "SELECT topicname, username, created, COUNT(commentid)
        FROM user,topic,comment
        WHERE topic.topicid = comment.whichtopic
        AND user.userid = topic.owner
        GROUP BY topicname";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo '<tr><th>' . $row["topicname"] . '</th><td>' . $row["username"] . '</td><td>'. $row["created"] .'</td><td>'. $row["COUNT(commentid)"] .'</td>
                <td><input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" id="checkbox[]" value="<? echo $row["topicname"]; ?>></td></tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
echo '<form name="form1" method="post" action=""> 
      <input name="delete" type="submit" id="delete" value="Delete">
      </form>';
if($delete){ 
    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){ 
        $del_id = $checkbox[$i]; 
        $sql = "DELETE FROM topic WHERE topicname='$del_id'"; 
        $result = mysql_query($sql); 
    }
}
```

Comment: I realize we're looking at just a fragment of your code, but Vicky points out $count is undefined, as is $delete and I don't see an action on your submit.

Comment: And your form tags shoud include your checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

you might be deleting in the wrong way

```
topicname='$del_id'
```

print the `$del_id` before executing the `DELETE` query. I think `topicname` is not finding any match. try this

```
 $sql = "DELETE FROM topic WHERE topicid ='$del_id'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
if(isset($_POST['delete'])){ 
        for($i=0;$i<count($_POST['checkbox']);$i++){ 
            $del_id = $_POST['checkbox'][$i]; 
            $sql = "DELETE FROM topic WHERE topicname='$del_id'"; 
            $result = mysql_query($sql); 
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Also keep the checkbox inside your form tags

Comment: happened nothing
Shows this error message:
"Notice: Undefined index: checkbox in C:\xampp\htdocs\asd\topicedit.php on line 84" which one is this line:
$del_id = $_POST['checkbox'][$i];